# How to find where Spring @Bean is injected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm configuring a Spring bean, for example:

@Bean
fun myService(): = MyService()

Is it possible to know where this bean will be injected?

I've tried to use BeanFactoryPostProcessor but there is no such possibility.

The only solution comes to my mind is to loop through all the beans and check constructor parameters via reflection. But parameter name could be different from bean name if there are no multiple beans of the same type.

Comment: You need to do this at runtime? What are you solving, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dependency detection interface

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        for (String bean: run.getBeanFactory().getDependentBeans("myService")) {
            System.out.println(bean);//the bean injected myService
        }
    }

}
```